# How to create a query with a constructor

Tags: jpa, constructor, jpql

I have to create a list of objects from a query that retrieve data from database and make some modification in order to display it correctly

for example i have a table

---

### Id |m1     |m2  |m3     |m4      |m5   |m6 |m8  |m9  |m10 |m11 |m12|

1 |janvier |mars|juillet|december|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|

---

this how rows are displayed into my DB
i want to reoder each row to get the right location in the list that i want to create
this how should display

---

### Id |m1     |m2  |m3  |m4|m5  |m6  |m8 |m9  |m10 |m11 |m12|

1  |1      |null|null| 1|null|null|1  |null|null|null| 1 |

---

that means if he founds 'janvier'  he will put 1 in the fist column
and if he find december he will he will in the 12st column

until now i created my entity named visite:

```
 package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Visite.findAll", query = "select o from Visite o") })
public class Visite implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6069673717468618734L;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String annee;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String client;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String dep;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String etat;
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String idvisite;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String ingaff;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m1;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m10;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m11;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m12;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m2;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m3;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m4;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m5;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m6;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m7;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m8;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String m9;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String moisvisite;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String nbvisites;
    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String prbvisite;

    public Visite() {
    }

    public Visite(String annee, String client, String dep, String etat, String idvisite, String ingaff, String m1,
                  String m10, String m11, String m12, String m2, String m3, String m4, String m5, String m6, String m7,
                  String m8, String m9, String moisvisite, String nbvisites, String prbvisite) {
        this.annee = annee;
        this.client = client;
        this.dep = dep;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.idvisite = idvisite;
        this.ingaff = ingaff;
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m10 = m10;
        this.m11 = m11;
        this.m12 = m12;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.m3 = m3;
        this.m4 = m4;
        this.m5 = m5;
        this.m6 = m6;
        this.m7 = m7;
        this.m8 = m8;
        this.m9 = m9;
        this.moisvisite = moisvisite;
        this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
        this.prbvisite = prbvisite;
    }

    public String getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setAnnee(String annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getDep() {
        return dep;
    }

    public void setDep(String dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public String getEtat() {
        return etat;
    }

    public void setEtat(String etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public String getIdvisite() {
        return idvisite;
    }

    public void setIdvisite(String idvisite) {
        this.idvisite = idvisite;
    }

    public String getIngaff() {
        return ingaff;
    }

    public void setIngaff(String ingaff) {
        this.ingaff = ingaff;
    }

    public String getM1() {
        return m1;
    }

    public void setM1(String m1) {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public String getM10() {
        return m10;
    }

    public void setM10(String m10) {
        this.m10 = m10;
    }

    public String getM11() {
        return m11;
    }

    public void setM11(String m11) {
        this.m11 = m11;
    }

    public String getM12() {
        return m12;
    }

    public void setM12(String m12) {
        this.m12 = m12;
    }

    public String getM2() {
        return m2;
    }

    public void setM2(String m2) {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }

    public String getM3() {
        return m3;
    }

    public void setM3(String m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }

    public String getM4() {
        return m4;
    }

    public void setM4(String m4) {
        this.m4 = m4;
    }

    public String getM5() {
        return m5;
    }

    public void setM5(String m5) {
        this.m5 = m5;
    }

    public String getM6() {
        return m6;
    }

    public void setM6(String m6) {
        this.m6 = m6;
    }

    public String getM7() {
        return m7;
    }

    public void setM7(String m7) {
        this.m7 = m7;
    }

    public String getM8() {
        return m8;
    }

    public void setM8(String m8) {
        this.m8 = m8;
    }

    public String getM9() {
        return m9;
    }

    public void setM9(String m9) {
        this.m9 = m9;
    }

    public String getMoisvisite() {
        return moisvisite;
    }

    public void setMoisvisite(String moisvisite) {
        this.moisvisite = moisvisite;
    }

    public String getNbvisites() {
        return nbvisites;
    }

    public void setNbvisites(String nbvisites) {
        this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
    }

    public String getPrbvisite() {
        return prbvisite;
    }

    public void setPrbvisite(String prbvisite) {
        this.prbvisite = prbvisite;
    }
}
```

and i created a new object in order to create a constructeur with parameters to use it in my session bean

```
package model;

public class VisiteConstructeur {
    private String annee;
    private String client;
    private String dep;
    private String etat;
    private String idvisite;
    private String ingaff;
    private String m1;
    private String m10;

    private String m11;
    private String m12;
        private String m2;
    private String m3;
    private String m4;
    private String m5;
    private String m6;

    public void setAnnee(String annee) {
        this.annee = annee;
    }

    public String getAnnee() {
        return annee;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setDep(String dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public String getDep() {
        return dep;
    }

    public void setEtat(String etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public String getEtat() {
        return etat;
    }

    public void setIdvisite(String idvisite) {
        this.idvisite = idvisite;
    }

    public String getIdvisite() {
        return idvisite;
    }

    public void setIngaff(String ingaff) {
        this.ingaff = ingaff;
    }

    public String getIngaff() {
        return ingaff;
    }

    public void setM1(String m1) {
        this.m1 = m1;
    }

    public String getM1() {
        return m1;
    }

    public void setM10(String m10) {
        this.m10 = m10;
    }

    public String getM10() {
        return m10;
    }

    public void setM11(String m11) {
        this.m11 = m11;
    }

    public String getM11() {
        return m11;
    }

    public void setM12(String m12) {
        this.m12 = m12;
    }

    public String getM12() {
        return m12;
    }

    public void setM2(String m2) {
        this.m2 = m2;
    }

    public String getM2() {
        return m2;
    }

    public void setM3(String m3) {
        this.m3 = m3;
    }

    public String getM3() {
        return m3;
    }

    public void setM4(String m4) {
        this.m4 = m4;
    }

    public String getM4() {
        return m4;
    }

    public void setM5(String m5) {
        this.m5 = m5;
    }

    public String getM5() {
        return m5;
    }

    public void setM6(String m6) {
        this.m6 = m6;
    }

    public String getM6() {
        return m6;
    }

    public void setM7(String m7) {
        this.m7 = m7;
    }

    public String getM7() {
        return m7;
    }

    public void setM8(String m8) {
        this.m8 = m8;
    }

    public String getM8() {
        return m8;
    }

    public void setM9(String m9) {
        this.m9 = m9;
    }

    public String getM9() {
        return m9;
    }

    public void setMoisvisite(String moisvisite) {
        this.moisvisite = moisvisite;
    }

    public String getMoisvisite() {
        return moisvisite;
    }

    public void setNbvisites(String nbvisites) {
        this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
    }

    public String getNbvisites() {
        return nbvisites;
    }

    public void setPrbvisite(String prbvisite) {
        this.prbvisite = prbvisite;
    }

    public String getPrbvisite() {
        return prbvisite;
    }
    private String m7;
    private String m8;
    private String m9;
    private String moisvisite;
    private String nbvisites;
    private String prbvisite;
    public VisiteConstructeur(String annee, String client, String dep, String etat, String idvisite, String ingaff, String m1,
                  String m10, String m11, String m12, String m2, String m3, String m4, String m5, String m6, String m7,
                  String m8, String m9, String moisvisite, String nbvisites, String prbvisite) {


        this.annee = annee;
        this.client = client;
        this.dep = dep;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.idvisite = idvisite;
        this.ingaff = ingaff;
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m10 = m10;
        this.m11 = m11;
        this.m12 = m12;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.m3 = m3;
        this.m4 = m4;
        this.m5 = m5;
        this.m6 = m6;
        this.m7 = m7;
        this.m8 = m8;
        this.m9 = m9;
        this.moisvisite = moisvisite;
        this.nbvisites = nbvisites;
        this.prbvisite = prbvisite;
    }
}
```

and here's my function where i'm blocked to make the conditions:

public List MyListResult() {

```
Query query =
    em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Visite o ");


List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
List<VisiteConstructeur> result = new ArrayList<>(rows.size());
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    result.add(new VisiteConstructeur((String) row[0],(String) row[1],(String) row[2],(String) row[3],(String) row[4],(String) row[5],
                                      (String) row[6],(String) row[7],(String) row[8],(String) row[9],
                                     (String) row[10],(String) row[11],(String) row[12],(String) row[13],
                                      (String) row[14],(String) row[15],(String) row[16],(String) row[17],
                                    (String) row[18],(String) row[19],(String) row[20]));


}
return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
public List<VisiteConstructeur> MyListResult() {
     List<VisiteConstructeur> result=  em.createQuery("select new model.VisiteConstructeur(annee,client,dep,etat,idvisite,ingaff,m1,
                  m10,m11,m12,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,
                  m8,m9,moisvisite,nbvisites,prbvisite)from Visite").list();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help my problem here how to assign  1 to m12 if there is 'december in the row'

Comment: u can use case when inside the query or use

Comment: can u explain me please?? i'm beginner in java

Comment: em.createQuery("select new model.VisiteConstructeur(annee,client,dep,etat,idvisite,ingaff,m1,
                  m10,m11,case when m12=december then 1 else null end,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,
                  m8,m9,moisvisite,nbvisites,prbvisite)from Visite").list();

Comment: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select new model.VisiteConstructeur(annee,client,dep,etat,idvisite,ingaff,m1, m10,m11,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7, m8,m9,moisvisite,nbvisites,prbvisite)from Visite]. 
[170, 170] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.